# Munin node not listing any plugins on new Fedora 14 installation

Tags: munin, fedora

I have just installed munin-node from the base repo on Fedora 14 and then started it. I found that my munin server is not able to collect data from this node so I tried connecting via telnet to test. When connecting via telnet I see that no plugins are listed:

```
[dave@host ~]# telnet localhost 4949
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
# munin node at host.example.com
list

quit
Connection closed by foreign host.
[dave@host ~]#
```

I did not modify anything after the installation. The munin-node.conf is allowing connections from 127.0.0.1 and the default set of plugins in `/etc/munin/plugins/` are symlinked to the plugins in `/usr/share/munin/plugins/`.

Here is the working output of the telnet test of the 'list' command should look like (this is on a Fedora 13 host):

```
[dave@www ~]$ telnet localhost 4949
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
# munin node at www.example.com
list
apache_accesses apache_processes apache_volume cpu df df_inode entropy forks fw_packets if_err_eth0 if_err_eth1 if_eth0 if_eth1 interrupts iostat iostat_ios irqstats load memory munin_stats mysql_ mysql_bytes mysql_innodb mysql_queries mysql_slowqueries mysql_threads netstat open_files open_inodes postfix_mailqueue postfix_mailvolume proc_pri processes swap threads uptime users vmstat yum
quit
Connection closed by foreign host.
[dave@www ~]$
```

Edited to show output of `munin-node-configure`:

```
[root@host ~]# munin-node-configure
Plugin                     | Used | Extra information
------                     | ---- | -----------------
acpi                       | no   |
amavis                     | no   |
...
http_loadtime              | no   |
if_                        | yes  | eth1 eth0
if_err_                    | yes  | eth0 eth1
ifx_concurrent_sessions_   | no   |
interrupts                 | yes  |
...
uptime                     | yes  |
users                      | yes  |
varnish_                   | no   |
vserver_resources          | no   |
yum                        | yes  |
zimbra_                    | no   |
```

Any suggestions on what to check next?

Comment: Take a look at the output of `munin-node-configure` on the node - do you get any "There were some errors" at the end? Does the "Used" column name any plugs with "yes"?

Comment: I edited my question to show the output of munin-node-configure. No errors and the default plugins show as being used. Permissions on the plugins match those on my other system as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope you edited your examples above and your actual hostname contains uppercase, because then it could be this one:

See https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=673263 and http://www.munin-monitoring.org/ticket/952

("Munin node returns an empty list of plugins with uppercase hostnames").

Comment: You got it! The kicker here is that the hostname no longer has uppercase characters but it did by default at installation time. I verified that the hostname currently is all lowercase but when I connect via telnet it shows an uppercase hostname. I'm guessing it was saved somewhere. I had to override this in the /etc/munin/munin-node.conf via the host_name directive.

Comment: Whew, that saved me tons of time, upgrade from Ubuntu server 8.04->12.10 broken munin...